# Fortran style implied do loop in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, printing

Can I use such "implied" for loops in C like Fortran? I am (happily) using gcc on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
    error: expected expression before ‘for’
      192 |    printf("e0 v0 %f %f %f %f %f %f  \n",for (unsigned i=0; i < 3; i++) e0[i],v0[i] );
```

Thank you for reading!  Best Season's Greetings!

Comment: In a word... No. You need to explicitly match 6 format specifiers, but you can rearrange the code to place `printf()` *inside* the loop, with 2 format specifiers.

Comment: Thank you. I can understand inside the loop, I did not want that, but can you please elaborate on "with 2 format specifiers"?

Comment: Like this `printf("e0 v0"); for(int i=0; i<3; i++) { printf(" %f %f", e0[i], v0[i]) }; printf("\n");` You say you "don't want to do it like this" but this is the way, and has about the same amount of code.

Comment: Thank you I will save this. I said I did not want because if I have other things to print, like some variables a,b,c, and then vectors, etc, it is nicer to get all done in 1 line. Thank you!

Comment: You can always write your helper functions, for example `print_vec3` or `print_array`.

Answer (score 1):

No, for a couple of reasons.

First and foremost, the syntax just doesn’t allow it. A `for` loop is a statement on its own, not an expression, so it cannot be an argument in a function.

Secondly, function arguments are fully evaluated before the function is called and the resulting values are passed to the function - you can’t pass an *expression* that the function executes internally.

In order to do what you want, you’d need to write

```
printf ( "e0 v0 " );
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  printf( "%f %f ", e[i], v[i] );
putchar( '\n' );
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Most  appreciated. Kind regards!